# How can I convert oauth2_token.value back to a Bearer token in simple_oauth?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I'm working on a headless Drupal 8 API that offers direct login links via email. For users who forgot their passwords or were invited but have never logged in, it's safe to just reset their password.

Otherwise, is there a way to convert the ~80 character strings in  `simple_oauth`'s table `oauth2_token.value` back into a Bearer token?

My currently implementation only resets the password as:

```
public function handle_otp(String $code, User $user, Group $group, Request $request) {
        $hash = \Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('myhash');
        $shouldbe = md5($hash . $uservariables);
        if ($code !== $shouldbe) $this->returnError(array('This is an invalid link'));

        $tokens = \Drupal::database()->query("SELECT id FROM oauth2_token WHERE status = 1 AND expire < now() AND auth_user_id=:uid LIMIT 1", array(':uid'=>$user->id()))->fetchAssoc();
        if (empty($tokens)) { // its safe to reset their password since they have no tokens
          $password = user_password(10);
          $user->setPassword($password); // reset password so we can request tokns
          $user->save();

          $params = array(
            "client_id" => \Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('client_id'),
            "client_secret" => \Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('client_secret'),
            "username" => $user->getEmail(),
            "password" => $password,
            "grant_type" => "password");

          $tokens = _run_curl($base_url.'/oauth/token', $params);          
          $tokens['randpass'] = $password; // give it back to the client to auto login
          $tokens['email'] = $user->getEmail();
        } else {
          // TODO: how do we convert oauth2_token.value to a Bearer token
        }

        return $this->sendToClient($tokens, $request);

     }
```

Comment: Check this out. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_oauth/blob/8.x-3.x/src/Entity/Oauth2Token.php The tokens are stored in oauth2_token table. The expiry time is set in expire field and the current status is in the status field which is returned in the isRevoked function. So if you manipulate these you should be able to extend tokens I believe.

Comment: i did look at that table but the `value` column have only 80 characters strings. it seems these are some encoding of the token? I haven't reversed back further than that yet. (hence this question)

Comment: Did you try changing the expiry time or the status columns and see if that has an impact?

Comment: @anoopjohn, all values i'm using have an active status and expiry... i've updated the question to focus the direction towards converting the oauth2_token.value to a bearer token